# HttpClient not storing cookies on galaxy s2

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient, galaxy

I'm trying to fetch data from a server with this code

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT);
    HttpRequestRetryHandler retryhandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(6, true);

    httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryhandler);

    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>8){
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    }
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);


    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
...
```

It's working fine with all the devices I tried so far except the Samsung Galaxy SII (android 4.0.3) of my client. From the server response, it seems like the session cookies are not stored. I failed to reproduce this bug and everything I tried so far didn't solve it. Do you have any clue ?

EDIT: removed a bloc of code who was disabling the StrictMode policy (still having the issue tho)

Comment: Are you performing the connection on a separate thread/asynctask?

Comment: yes i launch it on a asynctask. The thread policy is no more needed. Thanks for highlighting this :)

Comment: Yeah.. you def shouldn't just disable StrictMode... StrictMode is there for a reason :).

Comment: Can you update your code so that it is up to date? Did you remove the `StrictMode` block of code... did you do it differently...?

Comment: StrictMode block removed

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The problem was the fact that my phone was causing incorrect date so that all cookies were empty !!!

Comment: Great! Thanks, you save my day

Answer (score 1):

After many tries i found that the BasicCookieStore was not adding any cookie, because all cookies were expired for an unknown reason (and only on S2). I had to create my own implementation of CookieStore which ignore the expiration date check. This is a temporary fix, i'm still digging to find a more secure and clean way to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for writing this. It saved me quite some time debugging. 

I looked at tcpdump of a http post done on two different android phones (One with android 2.3.x and the other the Samsung galaxy s2 with android 4.03) and it was not apparent what went wrong by just looking at the requests. One worked while the other did not. Again, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :). Have you solved this problem ? So far the best thing i could was to rewrite the server script so that cookies are no more needed.

Comment: I am still debugging. I am using a HttpURLConnection to 
1) login (saving a PHP session cookie) 
2) upload an image and some text using http post.

I looked at the http requests/responses from when it work and does not work and they looks identical as far as the protocol goes. The only difference is the image file data. So I am not using the android cookie store or any other android method to save cookies automagically.

Comment: I got sessions to work by storing the session cookie received from a login php script (This is using HttpURLConnection) and then restoring it when calling the next php script which needs the session cookie. This works on the Samsung galaxy s2 phone.