# Android: File working in Emulator but giving error in Device?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, http-post

I am just trying to upload file to server through the code it working fine if I access file from Emulator,

path **data/app/07312012_135528.3gp** and gets server response **200, OK**

but when I access file to upload through Device is gives error **400, Bad Request** 
while file is present in **SDCard** and it passes the **File.exists()** check.

My Phone is **Samsung Galaxy Ace**

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(ServerURL);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "tdsongdata/07312012_135528.3gp");
// path becomes "/mnt/sdcard/tdsongdata/07312012_135528.3gp"

if(yourFile.exists())
{
    reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("esetylo@gmail.com"));
    reqEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody("123"));
    reqEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody("The new file"));         
    reqEntity.addPart("musicData", new FileBody(yourFile));
}
```

But When I **try to play it from the same path in Device it plays the Audio successfully**

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
        mp.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/tdsongdata/07312012_135528.3gp");
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start(); 
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I could not understand where the problem is, please help

Comment: If you get a different HTTP status code, the problem should be on your server.

Comment: Is your device in "Charge only" mode?

Comment: How to check if its in "charge only" mode.

Comment: Did you add the internet permission to your manifest?

Comment: yes I added INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in manifest ... it seems there is some file access problem .. but how to solve it ?????

Comment: As Azhar said, just make sur eyour SDcard is mounted when your phone is plugged via USB. Which means, If you ain't sure, just unplug your phone before you test your app...

Comment: Are you by any chance using cookies in connection with your upload? Like caused by a php session? Because another Samsung phone has issues with just this. I suggest you use tcpdump or wireshark to find out what you send to the server and if the http headers make any sense. While using HttpPost is easy, it is no longer supported by google and incomplete. You should use the Google supported alternative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331225/httpclient-not-storing-cookies-on-galaxy-s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your phone language to English (United States). Reboot your Device and try again.

Comment: Any chance you could explain why this is a solution? I'm curious how language affects his problem.